# JavaScript scroll detecting code not working

Tags: javascript

I have a code that detects when user is 0.6 from 1 to bottom of the page and then triggers a function. The code isn't working and i don't know why.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrZpyw?editors=1010

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
var a = document.body.scrollTop;
var b = document.body.scrollHeight - document.body.clientHeight;
var c = a / b;
console.log('Scroll position: ',c);
    if (c > 0.6) {
       generate();
       console.log(c);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.documentElement` instead of `document.body`:

```
var a = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var b = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.body.clientHeight;
```